# Hot Water Inconsistency

Tags: plumbing, hot-water

I've recently noticed an issue with the hot water in my shower.  After I start the shower water flow and wait for the warm water to start coming out, it stays warm for about a minute, then it gets luke warm.  At this point, it doesn't matter what I do with the control knob (I have a Mixet valve, FYI) - all the way hot, but it stays the same temperature.  I thought it was the water heater, but as a test, I left the tub hot water on during my shower and the hot water flowed the entire time.  It's like some other draw of hot water needs to be on in order for it to stay warm.  So then I thought it was the valve, which really made no sense to me but I replaced it anyway because it's easy and cheap.  The problem remains.  Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a tank type water heater or tankless? Is the shower head a low flow?  I've seen tankless water heaters "cycle" on and off when the demand is low causing fluctuations in shower temps.

Comment: Also meant to ask if you have hot water re-circulation?  I helped a friend a few weeks ago solve problem with inconsistent shower temps.   Turns out the plumber installed the re-circ pump backwards!  Which of course meant it was sucking cold/cool water out of the bottom of the water heater (tank type) and pushing it back into the hotwater pipe.  Depending who was using hot water and where determined how the shower performed!  Reversed the pump and problem fully solved.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson it's a normal tank-type.  No clue if I have a low-flow showerhead.  Is there something I can do to check and get back with you?  As far as I know, I don't have hot water re-circulation.  If I did, would it only apply to this one shower head?  Is there a way to verify this?  Thank you for the prompt response.

Comment: Most ppl don't have re-circ.  If you did there would be a small pump near the water heater connected to the cold water pipe near the inlet. Just thought I'd check.   At this point, I don't know what's going on.  Sorry.

Comment: No problem @GeorgeAnderson - I appreciate your time.